# How to get list of only custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am looking for a way to get all custom taxonomies but I could not find any way yet.

Is there any good way to get lsit of all custom taxonomies?

I tried to use get_taxonomies(); function but that return just default taxonomies not custom.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve *custom public* taxonomies with:

```
$args = [
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false  
]; 

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args );
```

but you should only try this after they have been registered, that usually happens during the `init` action.

Comment: Thanks for response.
How to do this AFTER they have been registered? I created taxonomy through wck plugin. So I don't know how to get taxonomies after they are registered.

Comment: Where are you adding/testing this code? This should work in your theme's files, appart from the `functions.php` file where you could try e.g. the `template_redirect` hook.  @AyyazZafar